# jquery error sending array of Strings to Spring application

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to send an array of strings to a java/spring backend solution and after trying to do it in many ways I gave up cause I always have errors (malformed request, missing body...)

I am pretty surprised cause followed many examples without success. I am sure the problem is in the jquery side cause I changed the method to GET in order to see the request as clear as possible and I saw the data is not represented as expected.

This is the function:

```
function duplicateSection() {

    var table = document.getElementById("tbody");
    var ids = [];
    var i = 0;
    var totalRows = table.rows.length;

    for(i; i < totalRows; i++){

        var checkbox = table.rows[i].cells[0].children[0];

        if(checkbox.checked){
            var id = table.rows[i].cells[1].children[0].value;
            ids.push(id);
        }
    }

    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(ids);
    alert(jsonString);

    $.ajax({
        url: './duplicatesections',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: jsonString,
        success: function(data) {

            alert('sent');
        }
    });
}
```

When I show with alert the JSON string I get the expected result: ["1"]

When the request is sent I get this other result: http://localhost:8080/duplicatesections?[%221%22]

Why do I have this representation?: [%221%22]

As an extra information, I am using spring boot and thymeleaf in case it is relevant.

Comment: Because double-quotes are not valid in a URL. Using GET for this type of request may not behave the way you want it to. If you want to "see the request as clear as possible", use a POST and inspect the request using the developer tool of your choice (Chrome Developer Tools, Firebug, etc.)

Comment: Got it, thanks for your comment

Comment: [%221%22] is URL-encoded "1", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 0):

send a POST request.

`$.ajax({
        url: './duplicatesections',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: jsonString,
        success: function(data) {
            alert('sent');
        }
    });`